# Is there a way to get an array of values from an array of blittable structs?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I have an array of blittable structs, so each struct is a fixed size and sequential in memory. I'm looking to make multiple arrays from this single array of structs. Here is the struct:

```
[Serializable]
public struct SpriteRenderInstruction : IComparable<SpriteRenderInstruction>
{
    public int SpriteAtlas;
    public float4 Transform;
    public float2 SpriteSize;
    public float4 Uv;
    public float4 Color;
    public int SortingLayer;
    public int SortingOrder;

    public int CompareTo(SpriteRenderInstruction other)
    {
        if (this.SortingLayer != other.SortingLayer)
        {
            return this.SortingLayer - other.SortingLayer;
        }
        else if (this.SortingOrder != other.SortingOrder)
        {
            return this.SortingOrder - other.SortingOrder;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.SpriteAtlas - other.SpriteAtlas;
        }
    }
}
```

The array of SpriteRenderInstructions are sorted, and then I need to turn them into an array of Transforms, an array of SpriteSizes, an array of Uvs, and an array of Colors. Since this is happening every frame, and I'm dealing with fixed sized structs, I was hoping there would be a way to get these 4 arrays without creating a copy. I know there are methods of getting these arrays using Linq:

```
float4[] transforms = spriteRenderers.Select(p => p.Transform).ToArray();
float4[] spriteSizes = spriteRenderers.Select(p => p.SpriteSize ).ToArray();
float4[] uvs = spriteRenderers.Select(p => p.Uv).ToArray();
float4[] colors = spriteRenderers.Select(p => p.Color).ToArray();
```

But these all create new arrays, I'd like to avoid allocating memory for this.

Comment: is there so much memory will be allocated?

Comment: It's for a rendering system in Unity, I'm trying to see how many sprites I can draw to the screen at once using a combination of their new DrawMeshIndirectProcedural API and ECS framework. My current goal is to push 100k sprites, and allocating 4 arrays of 100k elements every frame drops the performance quite a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't create an array (or span) of (for example) the transforms without making a copy, because the defining feature of an array (or span) is that the homogeneous values must be *contiguous*, but in this case: the values will *not* be contiguous - they'll be spread out among all the other parts of `SpriteRenderInstruction`.

If you absolutely need them as arrays, you'll need to copy; however, you should be able to reuse existing buffers between frames, and just overwrite the active portion (and track that!) - i.e.

```cs
float4[] transforms = Array.Empty<float4>();
// ^^^ retain these buffers between frames, presumably in a field

// etc
var len = spriteRenderers.Length;
if (len > transforms.Length)
{
    transforms = new float4[len]; // todo: possibly add padding
    // etc
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < spriteRenderers.Length; i++)
{
    var renderer = spriteRenderers[i];
    transforms[i] = renderer.Transform;
    // etc
}
```

and just remember to never look past `len` (in case the number gets smaller)

Comment: A good solution, since it solves my problem of allocating constantly.